# Unable to access images from within a war dependency

Tags: java, deployment, dependencies, war

I am building a maven web project which has dependency on another war.
The problem is that, code inside the war(dependency war) is unable to access images present in this war(dependency war)

for example,
inside the war there is an image tag accessing the image as 
"/static/images/tick.jpg"

```
http://hostname:port/static/images/tick.jpg  <---Unable to access
```

It works when i try to access image as

```
http://hostname:port/images/tick.jpg  <---Able to access
```

I cannot change the code inside the dependency war.

The directory structure is:

```
-target
    -m2e-wtp
        -overlays
            -static.war  <---- dependency
                -images
                    -tick.jpg
                -META-INF
                -WEB-INF
    -my project
        -images
            -tick.jpg
        -META-INF
        -WEB-INF
    -war
        -work
             -com.portal.webapps
                 -static
                     -images
                         -tick.jpg
    -my project.war <----war file
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to somehow specify where the resources should be deployed? If yes, how?

**IDE - eclipse**

**Server - Tomcat**

Comment: What does the final war look like?

Comment: Do you mean the structure of target folder?

Comment: Ah.  Would you be able to deploy static.war separately to the server - that should fix it.

Comment: I cannot deploy it separately. The structure of the target directory is mentioned in the question. Is there any way where I can tell eclipse that the "images" folder from static.war should be copied to "my project/static/images". "my project" contains the images at wrong path!